# Add post_id to post_title only to posts with a post_type of "post "

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to able to insert the id of the post in the post title.
The id should be added to the title everywhere the title appears.
It should only be added to posts with post type `post` and not added to pages, custom post types etc.

I've managed to get this far:

```
function custom1_shortcode_func() {
    global $post;
    ob_start();
    echo get_the_title($post->ID); echo " ("; echo get_the_ID(); echo ")"
    $output = ob_get_clean();
    return $output;
}
add_shortcode('post-id', 'custom1_shortcode_func');
```

Which returns the post title and the post id, when using [post-id] within a post.

But I need to have post titles modified all over my site, so wherever a post title is shown it is followed by "(post_id)".

I tried this and it did show the post_id before the post title, but it it changed all titles, including menus:

```
add_filter('the_title', 'wpshout_filter_example');
function wpshout_filter_example($title) {
    return get_the_ID().$title;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. The exact issue you're having isn't clear - I think you mean that your `add_filter` code changes the title everywhere it is used, but you only want the id added in specific places, is this right? Where exactly should the id appear, e.g. in the page geading onlt, in the title ( i.e. the title that shows in the browser tab), in links to the page, etc?

Comment: Hi FluffyKitten
I need the titles of my posts to be displayed like this: "post_title | post_id".
I can insert the post_id with the abve code, but it  also changes menu-items. 

I've tried various codes with no luck.

I've made this code, that inserts the title and the post id, and hoped i could just alter it. But inserting a shortcode like [post_id] in the titles does not render to the post_id but shows just the text: post_id]

Comment: function custom1_shortcode_func() {
        global $post;
 ob_start();
 ?>
  <?php echo get_the_title($post->ID); echo " ("; echo get_the_ID(); echo ")" ?>
 <?php

 $output = ob_get_clean();
     return $output;
     }
      add_shortcode('post-id', 'custom1_shortcode_func');

Comment: Yes, but *where* do you want the titles to be changed? You said `add_filter('the_title'...)` changed it but that you didn't want it to be changed everywhere. So which places do you want it changed in?

Comment: Sorry. I want all post titles changed. Where ever they are displayed.

Comment: I'm a bit confused,... I thought your `add_filter` function did that for you already, but you didn't want the id in the title in the menu?

Comment: Hi FluffyKitten, Thank you for your interest in my case. But it seems as i have not been able to explain to you what i need.

Comment: @Fluffykitten: There are two different codes above. The first works fine, but cannot be used in titles. My WP simply does not render the [post-id] when inserted in the title.

The second code also works, but adds the post_id to all titles on my site.

So i need to be able to insert the post_id in post titles. I feel like iøm halfway there with the codes above - but i still havent managed....

Comment: OK, I think I understand now.... you want to add it posts of the type "post" only, and not to custom post types, pages, etc? And it should be added everywhere the post title is shown, e.g. in the main heading on the webpage, the html `<title >` of the page and all auto-generated links to the post's page (e.g. latest posts, menus). Have I understood this correctly?

Comment: @FluffyKitten - yes :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close with your second attempt, but as you discovered that works for every title.

What you need to do is fist check the post type is a `post` and only add the id if it is.

```
add_filter('the_title', 'add_id_to_title', 10, 2);
function add_id_to_title($title, $post_id) {
    //use the id to check the post type and only add the id if it has a type of "post"
    if(get_post_type($post_id) == "post")
        $title = $post_id.': '.$title;
    return $title;
}
```

What this does:

- The [`the_title` filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_title) can take 2 parameters: title (which you were using) and also the id of the post.
- Using the id, can use the built-in [`get_post_type` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_type/) to find out the post type.
- Then we can  and check if the post type is `post` and if it is we add the id to the title.